# Text Area issue in IE11 - text content changed automatically

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textarea, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head></head>
<html>
<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I opened the html file in IE11 browser. I type "**cafe**" and hit a space after that. The content automatically get changed to "**café**". This issue is not happening every time. But once html file is loaded to the IE11 browser for the first time, issue is happening definitely.

Can anyone help me to understand the cause of the issue and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's IE's auto-correct "feature".

Either adapt your `textarea` as follows:

```
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" autocorrect="off"></textarea>
```

Or turn off auto-correct completely in your Windows settings.

Note: you can additionally turn off auto-capitalization, auto-completion and spell-checking:

```
<textarea autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"/>
```

Comment: Small note, there are users use this "feature", disabling might not be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you have autocorrect enabled in IE11.

> Disabling the Autocorrect in the Windows Settings (PC-Settings -> PC &
>   Devices -> Typing -> Spelling) is turned to "Off"

Comment: It's enabled by default. MS always knows best.